# Biblioteca para imagem do github para android que tem a opção de editar antes de carregar

Tags: android, imageview

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TVyRqsVtUulQABM9AtEDVv_iWmk5JY8_/view

Olá Senhores boa noite, alguém sabe uma biblioteca para android com essa função? ou como procurar no google? Estou desenvolvendo um app e está carregando a imagem direto no ImageView e não pega um angulo bom, com clareza, então queria usar uma biblioteca dessas que tem no github com essa função.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta primeira bilbioteca utilizei em alguns projetos e ela me atendeu muito bem, a segunda apenas testei para verificar as diferenças porém gostei mais da primeira(apenas minha opinião).

https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper

https://github.com/Yalantis/uCrop

Comment: muito obrigado, exatamente oque eu estava procurando